# How to rank similarities between sets of observations

Tags: distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Hi say I have a data frame where each row is a person and each column is measurement.  What I want to do is to find which persons are most closely related.  Say for example I want to test a and rank by most related in a descending order.

```
a <-  c( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
b <- c( 4.9, 1.5, 3.5, 4, 1.2 ) 
c <- c( 1.2, 1.5, 3.5, 4, 4.9)  
d <-  c( .9, 1.9, 3.2, 4.1, 4.9) 

df <- data.frame ( a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d)

ks.test ( df$a, df$b)
ks.test ( df$a, df$c )
```

I tried using the ks-test but it was not working for me since it does not take into consideration the order.  thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that the values are paired?

Comment: @Glen_b   no. each value is from a same measurement. For example say the first numbers in a, b, c is measuring height, second is measuring hair length and so on.. what I want to ultimately find out is which variable are most similar.  sorry if I'm not explaining corrrectly.

Comment: Each measurement is a variable, then. If they're measured on different scales (height and hair length) how are the differences comparable across scales?

Comment: @Glen_b yes that is  good point, what if I were to scale/normalize each of the measurements?

Comment: Even leaving aside the issue that the distributions may have quite different shapes (making a high deviation different from a low deviation for one variable but not for another variable), what about the impact of dependence? A pair of high deviations might be very different in implied lack of fit from one high and one low. You should probably explain more (in your question, rather than just in comments) about what kind of data you have and what you're trying to achieve, rather than starting from your own ideas about a solution -- it seems to be leading you astray.

Comment: @Glen_b ok good point. I will edit above.

Comment: Have you tried to cluster your data? The datapoints (persons) that fall into the same cluster should be the most closely related (in mean squared error sense).